# axios didn't return data with matching query string of parameter object but returns all the data in vanila JS

Tags: javascript, axios

i have an api endpoint https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries.

Now i am fetching all the countries by

`axios.get('https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries')`

it returns successfully. Besides I want to fetch single countries with the country code like 'BB' .and i am trying with params and my object is like below

```
axios.get('https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries',
 {
 params: {
 code: codeId
 }
```

but it returns all the data like above rather than showing a single country with the following code. I also want to extract only the currency and area code. I wanted to try like this, don't know it gonna work or not.

```
.then(axios.spread((object) => {
      console.log('Currency: ', object.data.currency);
      console.log('Area code: ', object.data.emojiU);
    }));
```

please someone help me... It took me almose the hole day for this but not able to success.

Comment: Are you in charge of the server that listens to `https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries`? Does it accept passing the country id to get the data of a specific country?
Should the request for a specific country return more detailed data? Or it would return the same data as you are getting when obtaining all countries?

Comment: if you enter https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/BB it will provide {"name":"Barbados","native":"Barbados","phone":"1246","continent":"NA","capital":"Bridgetown","currency":"BBD","languages":["en"],"emoji":"","emojiU":"U+1F1E7 U+1F1E7"}


i am not in charge, it was a task that was given by an employer 
it returns the same data. there is no country id .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, if you want to get the data of a specific country, you only have to append the country code id to the URL:

```
const codeId = 'BB';
axios.get(`https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/${codeId}`)
```

Would give you the data for Barbados.

If you want to access the `currency` attribute you can do so with the code:

```
const codeId = 'BB';
axios.get(`https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/${codeId}`).then(function(response) {
    const currency = response.data.currency;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work and showing data = "".  Actually I want to show the country with the user's request parameter. Which i grab with users input like

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" placeholder="Country Code ..."/><br/>

Comment: You can check that the code above is indeed working in the [following fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zv17se48/). Maybe the problem you are facing is getting the value of `codeId`?

Comment: oh.... finally it works. Thank you from the bottom of my heart. There is some other issue. like what if i want to fetch only the currency? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I expanded the answer to include how you would access the currency of the country you have fetched.

Comment: actually i already did that and it worked. But my program actually show it inside the html like    

resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response);

so .. it will be change the innerHTML with the above data.